# D3D9 Direct3DCreate9() Linker error, but all other D3D functions work

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, directx-9

I'm trying to create a wrapper for 'Direct3D9' for quick and easy 'DirectX 9' usage in my own application.  Everything compiles great except for the one and ONLY function "Direct3DCreate9".  If I comment that function out, then all other Direct X functions compile just fine. I downloaded the SDK (as I have before many times) from the Microsoft website https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812.

I tried linking the d3d9.lib inside of project settings for visual studio.
I tried using the #pragma comment linker
`#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")`

I cannot find any similar issues online.  Only issues related I can find are people who were legitimately not linking to the library.

```
        bool D3D9::Initialize(HWND i_hWnd)
        {
            D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
            ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
            d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
            d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
            d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = i_hWnd;

            // If I comment this line out, it compiles fine
            m_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION); // LINKER ERROR

            HRESULT hr = m_pD3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, i_hWnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &m_pDevice);
            return true;
        }
```

When I comment out the line of code calling `Direct3DCreate9` I expect there to be linker errors with all the other D3D calls on the Direct3DDevice itself.  But once I comment that one line out, there are no issues with compiling.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: this mean that you not add *d3d9.lib* to linker input. what linker you use ? *link.exe* ?

Comment: Yeah, I was linked to the lib.  It turns out I was linking to a bad .lib.  Like I said, all other D3D functions compiled fine.  It was only the Direct3DCreate9 that gave the linker error.

Comment: Note that Direct3D 9 is legacy, and there's very limited debugging support on Windows 10. There also few tools, utilities, or libraries for it. You should use DirectX 11. Take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it.

The issue was I needed to link to **Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86**.

I was linking to **Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64**.

Comment: Note that the DirectX SDK is legacy. See [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://aka.ms/dxsdk). In order to use the legacy DirectX SDK correctly with the Windows 8.1 SDK or Windows 10 SDK (which you have with VS 2015), be sure to see [this Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-#using-directx-sdk-projects-with-visual-studio) page.